Filling small gaps behind skirting board / baseboard
We've had some ants in our downstairs lately and noticed they were crawling under the skirting board/base board. I pulled the skirting off and noticed there are some small gaps behind it, where the floor tiles meet the wall.


The ants seem to be crawling in there and not originating from there as far as I can tell i.e. the gaps don't lead into a void somewhere (I hope). I'd like to fill the holes up so the ants don't start collecting behind here. What would be recommended to use to fill the holes before I put the skirting back? Someone suggested just using silicone to fill the gaps and put the boards back.
The skirting appears to be MDF and it was attached to the wall (plaster board) using what I assume is No Nails.
Thanks

If your concern is about ants, deal with the ants. Your house will never be hermetically sealed. (In other words, you can fill a crack or two, but ants will always find another.)

Thanks. I'm not looking to hermetically seal the house but fill these gaps behind the skirting boards so wanted to know the best method to fill said gaps.

More joint compound on the walls, maybe caulking at the floor level. But really this won't accomplish what you are trying to achieve - stopping ants. I must repeat the other comment, you have to deal with the ants, not the gaps. Traps, exterior sprays, etc.
